# Absolute div and z-index

Tags: css, html, position

I have a div with default `position` argument. Now I need to put under it another div:
[image]

```
#Dark
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    z-index: 999;
}

#Blue
{
    background-color: #046a81;
    height: 90px;
    width: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

How to put blue one layer down (it should be rendered before dark div) if I can't make `Dark` position as absolute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `#Dark` have `position:relative`. It still behaves as if it were in the flow, but now you can adjust the `z-index`.